# yup file validation changes instance of object

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I want to rewrite an old form using *react-hook-form* and *yup*. Everything went great until I tried to adapt some validation I made for an image upload. I use a package named *react-dropzone* (great package) which allows me to get a `File` object, then I use `setValue` to set it as my image.

I want to deny images over 5MB, and I want the images to be at least *minWidth* and at least *minHeight*

I rewrote my old function like that to use it as a validator with *yup* :

```js
const validateImageSize = (file, minWidth, minHeight) => {
  var img = new Image();

  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    img.onerror = (e) => {
      resolve(false);
    };

    img.onload = (e) => {
      let width = img.naturalWidth;
      let height = img.naturalHeight;

      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
      if (width < minWidth || height < minHeight) resolve(false);
      resolve(true);
    };
  });
};
```

When I get the file from react-dropzone, this function works fine, but if I use it as a yup validator, like that :

```js
    image: yup
      .mixed()
      .test("required", "You need to provide a file", (file) => file ? true : false)
      .test("fileSize", "The file is too large", (file) => file && file.size <= 5 * 1024 * 1024)
      .test("imageSize", "Image width and height should be at least 200x200",
        (file) => validateImageSize(file, 200,200))
```

1. The first test (required) works, because the object given by yup is or isn't `null`
2. The second test (fileSize) works, because when file is not null, it has a `size` property
3. The third test fails on that line :

```js
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

because the value given by yup is not an instance of File, and huh, I havent tested uploading it yet, but I'm not sure it would work. I still can test outside yup, and use directly the value from the input when uploading, but I have made a 50+ lines schema, in a dynamic form, it would be a shame having to override it, just for the image upload. Is there a way to handle that validation with yup, or will I have to it separately ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was wasn't yup, it was react-hook-form. It clones field values using this function : https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/src/utils/cloneObject.ts and thus I added another clause in the `if else if` list so that it passes the File object as is

Comment: Can you share the way you put it together ?