# Yup Image validation on Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, promise, yup

Continuing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287507/yup-file-validation-changes-instance-of-object), I want to expand this a little further but I feel I am limited by my knowledge on how Promise works.

I needed to use same to validate a list of files, but I noticed it ALWAYS returns true.

This is what I have done so far:

```
const validateImageSize = (file, minWidth, minHeight) => {
  if (file.constructor.name === 'Array') {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let wrongImages = file.filter((f) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(f);
        img.onerror = () => resolve(false);
        img.onload = () => {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
          console.log(!(img.naturalWidth < minWidth || img.naturalHeight < minHeight), ' ==>> ', img.naturalWidth, ', ', img.naturalHeight);
          return !(img.naturalWidth < minWidth || img.naturalHeight < minHeight);
        };
      });
      console.log('   =>  Len: ', wrongImages.length);
      resolve(wrongImages.length === 0);
    });
  } else {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      img.onerror = () => {
        resolve(false);
      };

      img.onload = () => {
        let width = img.naturalWidth;
        let height = img.naturalHeight;

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
        if (width < minWidth || height < minHeight) resolve(false);
          resolve(true);
        };
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my Schema:

```
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    is_delayed: Yup.boolean(),
    delay_evidence: Yup.array().when('is_delayed', {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.array()
        .min(1, 'Upload at least one picture')
        .test('required', 'You need to provide a file', (file) => (file ? true : false))
        .test('imageSize', 'Image width and height should be at least 200x200', (file) => validateImageSize(file, 200, 200))
    })
  })
```

I tested by uploading different image dimensions that should have failed but it often returns true

Comment: Your `filter` does not work. A `filter` callback must by synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` callback is broken, it doesn't return anything. You need to first load all the images, then check their dimensions.

```
async function validateImageSize(file, minWidth, minHeight) {
  if (Array.isArray(file)) {
    const results = await Promise.all(file.map(f => validateImageSize(f, minWidth, minHeight)));
    return results.every(Boolean);
  }
  try {
    const { width, height } = await getFileDimensions(file);
    return width >= minWidth && height >= minHeight;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The recursive call avoids code duplication. The helper function:

```
function getFileDimensions(file) {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = () => {
      resolve({
        width: img.naturalWidth,
        height: img.naturalHeight,
      });
    };
  }).finally(() => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can make the helper function to get the image's dimensions a lot simpler with [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap): `async function getFileDimensions(file) {  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(file);
  const { width, height } = bmp; bmp.close(); return { width, height }; }`